How to add an item that is not included in the listbox to a listbox in ASP.NET?
I need a control in ASP.NET webforms. When the user writes a text in this control and clicks enter, the relevant text should be selected and appear in the control. In this context, I tried Listbox, but it is not selected because the listbox is empty and the value entered by the user is not included so, I need a control that will work like listbox, but like a listbox, the user should select whatever he entered without checking whether the entered text is in it or not.
Expected result should be like this:

How can I do this?

Have you tried anything? Do you have any code you can share? See [mcve] for more info on what I mean.

Actually, a list box or checkbox list looks to be a good choice.
So, say this markup:
        <h3>Enter a text value</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server"
            width="200px"
            OnTextChanged="txtItem_TextChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
            CssClass="myrb2">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>

And say code behind:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' load some sample values into check box list
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("One")
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("Two")
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("Three")

    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub txtItem_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If txtItem.Text <> "" Then
        ' look for the item in the existing list

        For Each OneItem As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items

            If OneItem.Text = txtItem.Text Then
                ' item is in the list, check box, and exit
                OneItem.Selected = True
                Return
            End If

        Next

        ' if we get here, then entered text was not in the list
        ' add to list and check it
        Dim AddOneItem As New ListItem
        AddOneItem.Selected = True 'check the box
        AddOneItem.Text = txtItem.Text

        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(AddOneItem)
    End If

End Sub

And the result is this:
Typing in an existing item will cause that item to be checked.

And if we enter text not in the current list, then the item is added (and checked).
Hence this:

And I used a checkbox list, of which you can quite much style anyway you want.
Hence, I used this CSS for the checkbox list:
.myrb2 label {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border: 2px solid hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
}

.myrb2 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    display:inline-block;
    background: hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
}
.myrb2 input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:inline-block;
    background: hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

Edit: Assuming StackOverflow like tags and selecting
So, say this markup:
        <h3>Enter a text value</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server"
            width="200px"
            OnTextChanged="txtItem_TextChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h3>Selected items</h3>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkSelected" runat="server" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
            CssClass="myrb2 myxbox"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkSelected_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            >
        </asp:CheckBoxList>


        <h3>Choose Tags</h3>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkFromList" runat="server" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
            CssClass="myrb2 mycheckbox"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkFromList_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            >
        </asp:CheckBoxList>

And now code behind:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' load up the from list of choices
        chkFromList.Items.Add("ajaxcontroltoolkit")
        chkFromList.Items.Add("asp.net")
        chkFromList.Items.Add("browser")
        chkFromList.Items.Add("c#")
        chkFromList.Items.Add("vb.net")
        chkFromList.Items.Add("jquery-ui")

    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub txtItem_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If txtItem.Text <> "" Then
        ' look for the item in the existing list

        For Each OneItem As ListItem In chkSelected.Items

            If OneItem.Text = txtItem.Text Then
                ' item is in the list, do nothing
                Return
            End If

        Next

        ' now look for the tag in the allowable (from list)
        For Each OneItem As ListItem In chkFromList.Items

            If OneItem.Text = txtItem.Text Then
                ' item is in the list
                ' add this to the chkSelected list
                OneItem.Selected = True
                SetChecked()
                Return
            End If

        Next

        ' if we get here, then entered text was not in the list
        ' So, optional add to the list???
        ' add to list and check it
        'Dim AddOneItem As New ListItem
        'AddOneItem.Selected = True 'check the box
        'AddOneItem.Text = txtItem.Text
        'chkSelected.Items.Add(AddOneItem)

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub chkFromList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    SetChecked()

End Sub

Protected Sub chkSelected_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    For Each SelectedItem As ListItem In chkSelected.Items
        If Not SelectedItem.Selected Then
            ' uncheck this item in source list
            For Each FromItem As ListItem In chkFromList.Items
                If SelectedItem.Text = FromItem.Text Then
                    FromItem.Selected = False
                    SetChecked()
                    Return
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub SetChecked()

    chkSelected.Items.Clear()

    For Each FromItem As ListItem In chkFromList.Items
        If FromItem.Selected Then
            Dim ToItem As New ListItem
            ToItem.Text = FromItem.Text
            ToItem.Selected = True
            chkSelected.Items.Add(ToItem)
        End If
    Next

End Sub

And the result is now this:

And even typing in a tag works just fine, hence this:

And the css I used (and assumed font awesome) is:
<style>
    .myrb2 label {
        display: inline-block;
        background: lightgray;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: .5rem;
        margin-right:20px;
        border: 2px solid hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
        height:30px;
        font-family:"FontAwesome";
    }

    .myrb2 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
        display:inline-block;
        background: lightgray;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
    }
    .myrb2 input[type="checkbox"] {

          opacity: 0;
          cursor: pointer;
          height: 0;
          width: 0;
    }
    .mycheckbox label:before{content:"\f058\0000a0"
    }

    .myxbox label:before{content:"\f057\0000a0";
    }

</style>

So as a proof of concept, the above two examples are a great starting point for this question.

Based on your animation this doesn't appear to behave like OP asked for. It looks like they want behavior exactly like the Stack Overflow tag list that appears under questions when you edit or create a question. Specifically, this doesn't create the 'bubble' element in the input box like OP wants.

Well, with some css, I could format as desired.  The basic proof of concept is really all that matters here.  If you wish I can change the css to produce a box in place of a oval button if that makes you feel better.

Well, it's not exactly a trivial matter to get from this answer to OP's desired output, although for someone proficient with both CSS and ASP.NET it shouldn't be exceptionally difficult.

Actually, see my edit, the css is not a whole not different, and certainly not difficult css. The original code as a proof of concept was simple extended to create a StackOverFlow like tagging effect.

That's... a little closer, but still not what OP asked for, which, again, is typing a value that then causes the value to appear as a bubble/element in the input field.

Again, not 100% clear that's what the poster wants - since the screen shot shows a square, but it not clear "where" in that textbox the user could/would type.  If the poster is looking for the same effect as we have when selecting tags on SO, then the poster is free to come back and suggest as such.  And once again, I could modify as such.  The poster suggested using a listbox, but as noted, I think a checkboxlist works rather well.  And as I stated, to get something that looks like a tag with css was rather easy, was it not! And no information was provided for what the source list should be

I think it is clear, from this sentence in the question: "When the user writes a text in this control and clicks enter, the relevant text should be selected and appear in the control" (emphasis mine). This indicates they want the text to appear in the same control they're typing in.

Sure,  that makes sense.  However the op also mentions use of listbox that doesn't allow typing.  So it makes little sense to talk about using a control that doesn't allow typing.  While I posted some proof of concept,  and I also showed you how easy and minor the css is to get something looking like a tag? I think a client side solution is a better road here,  and boatloads of jQuery and other examples exist if a SO tag like effect is desired.  I think my failing here is attempting to use listbox or CheckBox as poster suggests. If poster comes back,  I'll post something based on jQuery

Yes I think OP mentions listbox simply because that's the control they tried with (unsuccessfully). A working solution need not concern itself with using a listbox. Of course, OP's question is a bit scant on their own implementation details/attempts, so that could change if they ever provide additional clarity.

The poster might like the example I have, since you can "hen peck" away at the tabs, and not have to type - certainly more phone/touch and even mouse friendly. And on purpose, I did avoid a client side solution for the sake of easy code. Regardless, I would hands down think the OP is looking for is as you state.  It was never clear if a existing list of choices is to restrict the choices.  A quick google hits at least a dozen client side jQuery/JavaScript samples that does as the poster is asking. If the poster comes back, and decides they want a SO effect, I'll bite with JavaScript example.
